# Mosquitto-Auth plugin not replacing %c in ACL with Client Id

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I set up a test user with the following in the ACL table:

```
other/%c/test
```

I then connect as that user with ClientId set to "ten".
I publish to this topic: `other/ten/test`
In the log I get...

```
mosquitto_auth_acl_check(..., client id not available, mosx15, other/ten/test, MOSQ_ACL_WRITE)
mysql: topic_matches(test/#, test/#) == 0
mysql: topic_matches(Status/#, Status/#) == 0
mysql: topic_matches(other/client id not available/test, other/%c/test) == 0
aclcheck(mosx15, other/ten/test, 2) AUTHORIZED=0 by none
```

Is there something I am supposed to do in the conf file to use this feature?

Comment: What build of Mosquitto are you using?

Comment: Loaded from Git 2 days ago. ver 1.5 then compiled by me

Comment: Unless you really need 1.5 I'd be tempted to try with the last 1.4.x build

Comment: As long a 1.4.x works with mosquitto-auth I dont have a problem